# Restfull API with only PATCH requests instead of PUT for better extensibility?

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework, patch, put

We are working on an API when most of resources need to be updated entirely or partially with a set of specific fields according to many use cases. We are planning to use only patch requests for updates since it gives more flexibility (update if field exists else ignore). creating PUT route for entire update and PATCH route for partial update for the same resource seems redundant since PATCH can do both depending on requested fields. Is this a good choice ? what are the benefits of using PUT instead of PATCH other than validating fields existence ? if PATCH can do entire an partial update why not using PATCH everywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that it's fair to suggest that PATCH completely supersedes PUT.

First, you've got the historical reasons why PUT is more popular than PATCH - it was implemented first. [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) proposing PATCH was published in 2010 and PUT has been around since the late 90's. So PUT is just more likely to be widely acceptable on most infrastructure (both client and server). If what you want to do is as easily described by PUT then PUT is just a better choice because it's more likely to be available and implemented correctly. Of course, this issue is decreasing in relevance all the time.

Beyond that there are reasons why you would choose to use PUT rather than PATCH.

- PUT is defined as an idempotent operation whereas PATCH is not and, in the general case, cannot be. So if, for some reason, your client re-posts a document via PUT then there's not so much of a problem as there might be if a PATCH request is applied twice.
- the document format for a PUT operation is well defined as being a modified representation of the resource - broadly speaking, PUT is symmetrical to GET (although there are exceptions for certain cases, such as fields not modifiable by the user). PATCH is not. It operates on a potentially *different* content type (e.g. diff-style). It's not at all clear what the semantics of a PATCH document should be and is highly implementation dependent. What if you've got a JSON-based resource and you want to add an element to an array? Do you need a JSON document containing the whole new array? Just the new value? How do you delete an element from a JSON document? Maybe you need to use a diff-style format - ooh, that's getting complex for simple changes. Ever tried reading a diff in the middle of the night to work out what's gone wrong?
- PUT provides a good model for how HATEOAS applications should work when they want to modify a resource -  read the existing state of the resource, change it in some way and then send the updated state back to the server. You *can* model this using PATCH, but it's actually more work - you have to read the existing state, collect together all the changes and then format them into the new format. On the server side you have to apply all those changes to the resource in some way. Much more complicated than with a PUT.
- from a client's perspective, you may be attempting to do *different* things when you're doing partial updates versus complete updates. Partial updates may happen for *specific* reasons, where it makes sense to model them as different operations and to get the server to hide the messy implementation details.

In all PATCH's main advantage over PUT is its greater flexibility, but that flexibility comes at the cost of complexity. It's no longer clear whether the request is idempotent (it's implementation dependent). Updates which occur are no longer verifiable as the *new* state, they have to be processed in some way - so the updated state of the resource is now some function of the old state and the patch to get the new state. But if all your updates are via PATCH then you can only be sure of the new state if you know the *original* state (or a snapshot) *and* all subsequent patches *and* the order they were applied in (basically, a journal). In comparison, PUT offers a simple guarantee - if you PUT a document and get a success (2xx) response code, then that document represents (or *should* represent) the new state of the resource. That kind of property makes it easier to reason about your application, and that sort of thing can *really* help when you're investigating issues at 3am.

Perhaps, though, the question to ask is whether it's entirely ReSTful to have many resources which *require* the added flexibility (*and* complexity) of PATCH? Are your resources now *too* coarse-grained for the kinds of changes which your clients wish to achieve? Would it be worth breaking big ones down into separate resources which each give the client the ability to choose which type of update they actually need to perform? Do your resources actually agglomerate disparate types of thing, which would be better modelled via a different URI structure?

Of course, PATCH was designed to solve a specific problem - partial updates - and it does that well. Where you've got resource which genuinely requires supporting a partial update then you should look into PATCH. But I wouldn't advise going overboard and making all updates via PATCH's.